# How to add a new row at the top of table in asp grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a new row to the dataTable here. Is there any way to add the new row at top of table instead at bottom.

```
DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["dsRAComponent"];
DataRow drCurrentRow;
drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
drCurrentRow["MODELNO"] = String.Empty;
drCurrentRow["MODELDESC"] = String.Empty;
drCurrentRow["QTY"] = 0;
dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

Session["dsRAComponent"] = dtCurrentTable;
//Rebind the Grid with the current data
gvReceivedComponent.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
gvReceivedComponent.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows.InsertAt(drCurrentRow, 0);
```